# Filtering with Matching in Hadoop/Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to learn Hadoop/Pig and have been working on AWS,

Date looks like this (each column contains various websites):

```
 <http://openean.kaufkauf.net/id/businessentities/GLN_7654990000088> 
 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#isDefinedBy> 
 <http://openean.kaufkauf.net/id/businessentities/> 
 <http://openean.kaufkauf.net/id/businessentities/GLN_6406510000068> .
```

I am trying to filter for rows that contain 'business' in them but the filter keeps returning 0 records. my_data is formatted as above with 3 columns and the first column is subject which is displayed above and what I am trying to filter on. I have:

```
filter1 = FILTER my_data BY subject=='.*business.*';
```

Not sure why this is returning nothing as 'business' is definitely in 3 of the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
filter1 = FILTER my_data BY (subject matches '.* business.*');
```